# Posicionar JPanels na vertical

Tags: java, swing, layout

Eu estou tentando adicionar 4 painéis, de maneira que ficassem um abaixo do outro. Então, resolvi usar o `BorderLayout`, junto com o "posicionamento" (`NORTH`, `SOUTH` e etc), passar um `index`, porém, ele acaba pulando o segundo painel.

O `BorderLayout` não admite colocar componentes no mesmo "posicionamento" ?

ex: 2 painéis com orientação `CENTER`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass e = new NewClass();
        e.setVisible(true);
    }

    public NewClass() {
        add(painel());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JPanel painel() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel painel01 = new JPanel();
        painel01.add(new JLabel("Painel 01"));
        painel01.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        JPanel painel02 = new JPanel();
        painel02.add(new JLabel("Painel 02"));
        painel02.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        JPanel painel03 = new JPanel();
        painel03.add(new JLabel("Painel 03"));
        painel03.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        JPanel painel04 = new JPanel();
        painel04.add(new JLabel("Painel 04"));
        painel04.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        painel.add(painel01, BorderLayout.NORTH, 0);
        painel.add(painel02, BorderLayout.CENTER, 1);
        painel.add(painel03, BorderLayout.CENTER, 2);
        painel.add(painel04, BorderLayout.SOUTH, 3);
        return painel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nenhum dos componentes tem tamanho definido. Tente definir isso pra ver se resolve.

Comment: Coloquei tamanho, porém não resolveu !

Comment: Outro detalhe óbvio, você está adicionando 2 paineis no mesmo local(CENTER), é esperado que um sobreponha o outro. Se quer distribuir varios paineis, borderlayout nao é o recomendado. Use gridlayout  ou boxlayout

Comment: tem como me dar um exemplo desse gridlayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você colocar 2 componentes na mesma posição no `BorderLayout`, eles irão ocupar o mesmo espaço dentro do container. Pro layout, você está sobrepondo um sobre outro.

Para posicionar os 4 painéis em linha verticalmente, você poderia criar apenas 3 painéis, adicioná-los nas 3 posições do `BorderLayout`(norte, centro e sul), e no painel central adicionar mais 2, mas isso só aumentaria a complexidade algo simples. Talvez a forma mais adequada seria utilizando o [**GridLayout**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), configurando 4 linhas e uma coluna:

```
private JPanel painel() {
    JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    painel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

    JPanel painel01 = new JPanel();
    painel01.add(new JLabel("Painel 01"));
    painel01.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

    JPanel painel02 = new JPanel();
    painel02.add(new JLabel("Painel 02"));
    painel02.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

    JPanel painel03 = new JPanel();
    painel03.add(new JLabel("Painel 03"));
    painel03.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

    JPanel painel04 = new JPanel();
    painel04.add(new JLabel("Painel 04"));
    painel04.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

    painel.add(painel01);
    painel.add(painel02);
    painel.add(painel03);
    painel.add(painel04);
    return painel;
}
```

O resultado é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que o construtor deste layout recebeu 2 parametros, onde o primeiro é a quantidade de linhas e o segundo de colunas.

Comment: Então, mais embaixo um do outro não ele fica com esse BorderLayout pelo que voce disse ?

Comment: @Javinha nao entendi.

Comment: eu queria um baixo do outro, "alinhadinho" igual no exemplo que postei, o unico problema é que la ele não colocava os 4. Porque como você disse ele estava sobrepondo. Vou tentar com outro layout.

Comment: @Javinha veja a edição.

Comment: nossa, muito bom ! obrigado.